# dirichlet boundary condition and first derivatives

Tags: fourier-series, laplace-transform, boundary-value-problem

I am interested in solving an ODE of the form:
$$y''[x]+y'[x]+y[x]=g[x],$$
with the boundary condition $y[0]=y[L]=0$. Is expressing $y[x]$ in terms of its Fourier sine series of any use in this context, given the presence of the first derivative term? Analogously, is the Laplace transform of any use, given that the boundary condition does not involve the first derivative of y[x]? Are there alternative approaches that I may consider? Thank you.

Comment: that depends sometimes on $g$ and how good you can transform it. What happens if you try these methods?

Comment: I'm really interested in the general case, let's assume that g[x] is sufficiently regular to admit Fourier series and Laplace representation. The problem here is that the Fourier sine series expansion of the ODE introduces a cosine in the transformation of the first derivative and a sine in all the other terms, and thus I cannot solve the equation mode-by-mode. The Laplace transform of the second derivative, instead, return the derivative of y evaluated at x=0, i.e. y'[0], which is not given by the boundary condition.